# Split interface into multiple when using repository pattern in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, interface, repository

I have a `EloquentCompanyRepository` class which implements `CompanyRepository` interface. The interface consist of such methods as `find`, `all`, `save` and other common methods. Plus it has some methods like `saveEmail`, `saveCall`, `saveSms`. Apart from `EloquentCompanyRepository` there are some other classes which have `saveEmail`, `saveCall,` `saveSms` methods.

I want to split the `CompanyRepository` interface into separate files. Basic `EloquentRepository` and some interfaces like `EmailableContract`,`CallableContract` and `SmsableContract`.

However I don't understand, what will be the binding in the service provider? What interface should I use in controllers? There is a situation when a repository will implement only `EloquentRepository` and `EmailableContract` for example. And I can't use both interfaces in controller, since if I want to get a `EloquentCompanyRepository` class and it implements only these two interfaces, then what should I use in $app->bind?

I just don't like to repeat all these methods like find, all, saveEmail etc in multiple repositories

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5 you have something that is called [Contextual Binding](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/container#contextual-binding). You can bind given implementations to different controllers with same requirements like this:

```
$this->app->when('App\Handlers\Commands\CreateOrderHandler')
     ->needs('App\Contracts\EventPusher')
     ->give('App\Services\PubNubEventPusher');
```

This way you are saying "When CreateOrderHandler needs EventPusher give it an instance of PubNubEventPusher".

Comment: Ah yeah, but, for example my EloquentCompanyRepository implements EloquentRepository and EmailableContract. In CompanyController I need both methods for saving company emails and for common methods like find/save/delete etc. So which one interface I'll choose to use? It has no sense to inject EloquentRepository into constructor and then use it like $this->company->saveEmail

Comment: @Victor while your point is valid, I think that your app structure is not very good like this. Repositories should be only used for retrieving/creating/updating objects. Sending emails is not their job, you can handle this by using events and event listeners. This way your code logic will be well organized and easy testable.

Comment: By "saveEmail" I mean to store the email for a company, while sending is handled by event handler. So actually in repositories I have a lot of traits like emailable, callable etc and their job is to store an email, call or something else in DB. And just because it's convenient I use saveEmail in company repository because it's easier to work with polymophic relationships